# jQuery tooltip hover still running after mouse out

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a simple tooltip:

CSS:

```
  html {
      font: 100% calibri;
    }

    ul {
      margin: 100px 0 0;
      padding: 0;
      list-style-type: none;
    }
    ul li {
      padding: 0;
      margin: 0 2px;
      float: left;
      position: relative;
      text-align: center;
      background-color: #ccc;
    }
    ul li a {
      padding: 14px 10px;
      display: block;
      color: #000;
      width: 144px;
      text-decoration: none;
      font-weight: bold;
    }
    ul li em {
      background-color: #ccc;
      width: 180px;
      height: 45px;
      position: absolute;
      top: -85px;
      left: -15px;
      text-align: center;
      padding: 20px 12px 10px;
      font-style: normal;
      z-index: 2;
      display: none;
    }
```

HTML:

```
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Home</a>
      <em>This takes you home</em>
    </li>

    <li>
      <a href="#">Services</a>
      <em>This shows you our serivces</em>
    </li>

    <li>
      <a href="#">About Us</a>
      <em>This shows things about us</em>
    </li>

    <li>
      <a href="#">Contact Us</a>
      <em>Your can message us.</em>
    </li>
  </ul>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('ul a').hover(function(){
      $(this).next('em')
      .animate({
        opacity: 'show',
        top: '-75'}, 'slow');
    }, 
      function(){
        $(this).next('em')
        .animate({
          opacity: 'hide',
          top: '-85'
        }, 'fast');
    });

});
```

Result:

https://jsfiddle.net/fsxm1Ldt/

If I hover my mouse to and fro several times over the tooltip it will come in and out and will not stop until it completes the number of times I hovered in and out. How can I prevent it from doing this?

Comment: I'm afraid you can't - everytime you hover over, it basically goes in a queue - and based on my experience, you can't stop it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because the animations are being queued and then executed in turn.

jQuery has a function called [`.stop()`](https://api.jquery.com/stop/) which is for this kind of situation. It allows you to stop the current animation and also clear the queue of any others. This prevents the flickering effect you're seeing.

Your code becomes:

```
$('ul a').hover(
    function () {
        $(this).next('em')
            .stop(true, true).animate({
                opacity: 'show',
                top: '-75'
            }, 'slow');
        },
    function () {
        $(this).next('em')
            .stop(true, true).animate({
                opacity: 'hide',
                top: '-85'
            }, 'fast');
    }
);
```

Here it is in action: https://jsfiddle.net/fsxm1Ldt/2/

Answer (score 0):

You don't need Javascript or jQuery at all for this. Use css transtition and `:hover` instead:

```
ul li em {
  /* remove display: none; */
  opacity: 0;
  transition-duration: 0.4s;
}
ul li a:hover + em {
  opacity: 1;
  top: -75px;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/fsxm1Ldt/3/

Comment: Problem is not all browsers support this.

Comment: I wouldn't exactly call those browsers.

Comment: Also, I'd use JS only as a fallback for those browsers that need it.